# How to edit function setItem in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage, instrumentation

I've managed to instrument functions in Javascript by creating another function, adding my own functionality to it and then invoking `apply(this, arguments)` :

```
window["functionA"] = function(){...}
```

On Google Chrome I also managed to instrument function `setItem` which belongs to `localStorage` so instead I wrote:

```
localStorage["setItem"] = function(){...}
```

The above works brilliantly, writing `localStorage.setItem` instead of `localStorage["setItem"]` also works.

Although this works on Google Chrome, on Firefox `localStorage["setItem"]` or `localStorage.setItem` are treated as stored items in `localStorage` instead of new functions, so whenever `localStorage["setItem"] = function(){...}` is invoked, `function() {...}` is stored as a String in location `setItem` in `localStorage`. Does anybody have any idea why Firefox treats this differently than Chrome or if there exists any sort of work around to this problem?

Comment: IMHO what you're doing is not the best way to go about this. I would wrap `localStorage.setItem` with another function that does what you want and use that instead.

Comment: Are you trying to override setItem?

Comment: Not exactly, I'm creating a new function in setItem that executes my additional code while also executing its original code. I'm achieving this by including .apply(this, arguments). In Chrome this works fine but I don't know why in Firefox it doesn't.

Comment: the only real answer we can give: dont do this. ever.

Comment: Don't do this for setItem or don't do this for all functions (including the ones I create)? And is there a reason why?

Comment: the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#storage-2) are very vague about the behaviour. so i wouldnt rely on any beahviour here

Comment: And this is called MonkeyPatching, you should only do this if there is no other way to solve this.

Comment: This was the only method I found that works for functions that I created. But since I have to make use of setItem I'm required to apply this method on it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried patching the prototype of Storage instead?

```
Storage.prototype.setItem = function(key, value)
{
  //
}
```